# How to convert IOrderedEnumerable to IOrderedQueryable

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable, iqueryable

Invoking [AsQueryable()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb507003.aspx) on an `IOrderedEnumerable` invokes the extension method on `IEnumerable` and returns an `IQueryable` rather than `IOrderedQueryable`.

This doesn't really make sense to me. I would imagine that there should be an `AsQueryable` extension method on `IOrderedEnumerable` that returns `IOrderedQueryable`.

So my question has two parts:

1. Should there be a `public static IOrderedQueryable<TElement> AsQueryable<TElement>(this IOrderedEnumerable<TElement> source)` extension method? If not, why?
2. How would you currently convert a `IOrderedEnumerable` to `IOrderedQueryable`?

   ```
   IOrderedEnumerable<string> orderedEnumerable = new List<string>().OrderBy(s => s);

   IOrderedQueryable<string> orderedQueryable = // how can I convert orderedEnumerable here?
   ```

Answer (score 8):

1. I honestly can't answer that question. The problem is `AsQueryable()` is defined on the `IEnumerable` interface, and overriding it might be an issue. You could probably define your own `AsOrderedQueryable()` extension reasonably easily.
2. You have to apply the sorting after calling `AsQueryable()`. so `new List<string>().AsQueryable().OrderBy(s => s);` will return an `IOrederedQueryable<string>`.

EDIT: So in regards to your original question, you would write

`IOrderedQueryable<string> orderedQueryable = orderedEnumerable.AsQueryable().OrderBy(s => s);`

It's a little roundabout, but the relationship is that you turn an `IEnumerable` to an `IOrderedEnumerable` using `OrderBy`, and you change `IQueryable` to `IOrderedQueryable` via the same method. No direct method of conversion exists between `IOrderedEnumerable` and `IOrderedQueryable` AFAIK.

Comment: "overriding it might be an issue"... I don't think it would be. IQueryable derives from IEnumerable, and both implement many identically named extension methods.

Comment: @ZaidMasud It doesn't implement its own, it inherits them. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.iqueryable.aspx

Comment: I mean that `IEnumerable` has a [Where](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx) extension method and `IQueryable` also has a [Where](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535040.aspx) extension method. And `IQueryable` inherits from `IEnumerable`, just like `IOrderedEnumerable` inherits from `IEnumerable`. So there's no reason that `IOrderedEnumerable` can't have an `AsQueryable` extension method. And by the way, while we're discussing technicalities, extension methods are static and static methods cannot be inherited.

Comment: I think if you call .Sort(s=>0) it will maintain the previous sort order where as .Sort(s=>s) might cause you problems if you had sorted the original collection in a different / dynamic manner order. There will still be a cost with this call, but it shouldn't be too bad